# WordPress, nginx proxy and subdirectory: wp-login.php redirects to domain

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, nginx

In my NGINX configuration, a WordPress blog is on a private server. My NGINX public server proxies the private server's content for *https://www.example.com/blog/*.

```
location ^~ /blog/ {    # A "subdirectory", hiding a proxied server

    proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.5:80/;    # The blog resides in the 
                                                       # private's web root, 
                                                       # not in a subdirectory
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect          off;
}
```

The blog is perfectly rendered on calling the domain and subdirectory. Bringing up wp-login *does not* generate a *redirect* GET field.

https://www.example.com/blog/wp-login.php

My siteurl and my home variables are both set to the domain with subdirectory.

However, after a successful login, I may see the dashboard, but the URL in my browser gets rewritten to https://www.example.com/wp-admin, causing problems on using the dashboard.

How do I configure WP to rewrite the URL to the subdirectory, although the blog is on a proxied private server?

(Do the subdirectories in the servers have to be symmetrical?)

Answer (score 26):

I have also met with same problem, 
I found a workaround, to fix the issue, add below code to **wp-config.php**

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: Lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you

Comment: It does not work. Wordpress redirects from `/blog` to `/wp-admin` (instead of `/blog/wp-admin`.

Answer (score 11):

WordPress uses two variables to define where it is hosted: `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL`. Both can be set using the dashboard, but I prefer to set them in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com/blog' );
```

It is usual to set an absolute URL (as above) which includes scheme and host name, but I prefer to use a relative URL when operating behind a reverse-proxy, like this:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', '/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', '/blog' );
```

You can probably continue to run WordPress in the root of your private server (assuming it isn't accessed directly). Moving the private server down one level is a little more complicated and involves the web server configuration on both servers to be changed a little.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful when trying to proxy_pass with nginx

Comment: Note: If you have access to the database, you can just edit 'siteurl' and 'home' in phpMyAdmin or something.

Comment: Relative urls does not work in v5.x, shows error `The Site address you entered did not appear to be a valid URL. Please enter a valid URL.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following two rewrites to your **wp-config.php**:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-login.php", "/blog/wp-login.php", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

The first one fixes all admin pages. The second one you need for the password reset flow.

I found an open [TRAC issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42610#no0) for the password reset flow from 4 years ago, so it seems we'll have to continue doing these workarounds for the foreseeable future. It doesn't seem like running behind a reverse proxy is something Wordpress expects most people to do.