# Set up Nginx to route to Node app and Wordpress

Tags: node.js, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have an Amazon AWS instance running WordPress and a Node application on port 8080. I need to set up my Nginx configuration such that navigating to `www.example.com` will take you to the Node app and navigating to `www.example.com/blog` will take you the WordPress site. Currently navigating to `/blog` will load the HTML but not the CSS or JS.

My config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location @blog {
        rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blog/index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location /blog {
        index index.php;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;
        alias /var/www/html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have your Wordpress site files in "blog" directory

Comment: No it's in /var/www/html

Comment: So move all those files in blog directory

Comment: I did and it's still not working. The issue is that WordPress is looking for files in /wp-content/plugins/ instead of /blog/wp-content/plugins.

Comment: You need to tell WP that it lives at `/blog`. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090577/wordpress-nginx-proxy-and-subdirectory-wp-login-php-redirects-to-domain/34091251#34091251)

Comment: @RichardSmith setting WP_SITEURL to /blog and WP_HOME to / did the trick. But now index tries to look for sciprts in /blog/blog/blog/wp-content

Comment: Did you have problems when both values were set to `/blog`? I have never run WP without both values being the same.

Comment: When both were set to /blog the url was /blog/blog. One of my plugins got messed up in the transition and removing it fixed all my issues. Cheers!