# ngix proxy wordpress and apache cannot access wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a private server to run apache and wordpress and a another server with public ip to run ngigx. Here is some information on private server:

```
IP: 192.168.0.10:8080/blog
     I can visit anything before i change home/siteurl in admin setting.
wordpress forld "/var/www/html/blog/"
both home and siturl are "www.example.com/blog" set in admin settings
```

On public sever (www.example.com) ngnix configuration：

```
        location ~ ^/blog {
            proxy_pass "192.168.0.10:8080";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect          off;
        }
```

I can visit `www.example.com/blog` and its blogs without problems. But when I click login button, it link to `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-login.php`, but get a page like:
[image]

(there is no css/js loaded) and get `301 Moved Permanently` for http://www.example/blog/wp-admin/load-styles.php.... and then redirect to https://www.exmaple.com/blog/wp-admin/load-styles.php It seems that I cannot visit anything in `blog/wp-dmin/`
I have try the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091251/2256235
but it might not work for me. Anyone can help me? I have stucked in it for tow days. Many thanks