# Wordpress admin in subdirectory redirects without subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, proxy

I have my wordpress set up through a proxy. The URL on my main site is https://DOMAIN/blog

Here is the apache set up for my proxy:

```
 SSLEngine on
 SSLProxyEngine On
 SSLProxyVerify none
 SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerName 
 SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass /blog/ https://104.xxx.xx.xx/
 ProxyPassReverse /blog/ https://104.xxx.xx.xx/
```

This is working ok. When I go to https://DOMAIN/blog, it is proxying me to https://104.xxx.xx.xx as it should

The frontend of wordpress actually works perfectly, no issues at all.

The problem is in the admin, when I go to https://DOMAIN/blog/wp-admin. It logs in ok, but it redirects me to https://DOMAIN/wp-admin and 404s (since https://DOMAIN/wp-admin isn't proxied)

Here's my .htaccess for 104.xxx.xx.xx

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried changing .htaccess about every way I can think of changing (setting RewriteBase /blog/, messing with my redirect rules, and a thousand other things).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your RewriteBase is wrong. Add your folder. Should be RewriteBase /blog

Comment: I tried that, didn't help at all

Answer (score 2):

You have the solution in your own comment already: 
"(since DOMAIN/wp-admin isn't proxied)"

wp-admin area is domain subfolder on its own and therefore must be proxied.
Or you have to tell your proxy to rebuild all requests of DOMAIN/wp-admin into DOMAIN/blog/wp-admin.

Your changes to .htaccess on the blogs machine are not effective because requests to DOMAIN/wp-admin are not proxied and never reach your blogs server.

I also just now found a more elegant answer from Bukky i want to share:
[WordPress, nginx proxy and subdirectory: wp-login.php redirects to domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090577/wordpress-nginx-proxy-and-subdirectory-wp-login-php-redirects-to-domain)

(the one where you edit wp-config.php)