# Why doesn't WP_SITEURL apply to links in wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress on its own host running behind an nginx reverse proxy that terminates SSL connections. I have it all working now, but there is one change I needed to make that I don't understand.

In my `wp-config.php`, I have these two variables set:

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://yoursite.com/blog');
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://yoursite.com/blog');
```

However, when I would logg into the admin dashboard, any link that I would click would NOT have `/blog` in the path and it would 404 (`https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/themes.php`).

I fixed this by adding this to the config:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

But why is this needed? Isn't `WP_SITEURL` all you need to determine the
base URL" for internal links?

Comment: I would try restarting your server and checking settings. It 100% works based on WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL.

Comment: @MarkTruitt I restarted the server and found that I still need that `str_replace` in there. I think it might be related to my particular reverse proxy setup

Comment: Ya, thats very possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090577/wordpress-nginx-proxy-and-subdirectory-wp-login-php-redirects-to-domain/71004709#71004709